# Swift issue in Swift for Beginners Chapter 6

Tags: swift

This line of code from "Swift for Beginners" won't work on the latest Swift Version. I'm guessing the `repeat` keyword can no longer be used as is in the code, so if I change it to `repeato`, the code loops 5 times as expected but only shows "()" in the console, without the actual String. How can this be fixed?

here is the simple code:

```
// extension with a closure as a parameter
extension Int {
    func repeat(work: () -> ()) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            work()
        }
    }
}
5.repeat({
    println("repeat this string")
})
```

Comment: `println` is now `print` and output shows up in the debug area at the bottom of the screen.  Make sure you open that up by selecting the middle icon in the upper right of the Xcode screen.

Comment: Thanks vacawama, I didn't think of opening debug area :) that works!

Answer (score 0):

Changes in Swift 2:

- `repeat` is now a keyword
- `println` is now `print`

This should work:

```
extension Int {
    func times(work: () -> Void) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            work()
        }
    }
}

5.times {
    print("repeat this string")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, the code actually worked, but as vacawama stated, the expected output is now in debug area. It was there all the time, just that I didn't look there :) silly me.